# How to filter rows in the powershell which are taken from console program?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have an `.exe` console program which put the result into the console in the following format:

```
 ------------------ ----------- ----------------
  CompanyName        CompanyId   CompanyType
 ------------------ ----------- ----------------
  test1              1           Root
  test2              2           Center
  test3              3           Company
 ------------------ ----------- ----------------
```

I would like to pick up this in a PowerShell script and filter by the `CompanyName`.

I tried it with:

```
MyTool.exe companies | where {$_.CompanyName -eq 'test1'}
```

but it seems that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to convert the output of an EXE to a powershell collection of objects. what it does ...

- creates a fake version of the output of your exe file
- filters out the lines with repeated hyphens
- replaces leading spaces with nothing
- replaces 2-or-more spaces with a comma
- converts that CSV-like string array into a collection of powershell objects

here's the code [*grin*] ...

```
# fake getting string output from an EXE
$InStuff = @'
 ------------------ ----------- ----------------
  CompanyName        CompanyId   CompanyType
 ------------------ ----------- ----------------
  test1              1           Root
  test2              2           Center
  test3              3           Company
 ------------------ ----------- ----------------
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$CompanyInfo = $InStuff -notmatch '--{2,}' -replace '^ {1,}' -replace ' {2,}', ',' |
    ConvertFrom-Csv

$CompanyInfo
'=' * 30
$CompanyInfo -match 'Test1'
```

output ...

```
CompanyName CompanyId CompanyType
----------- --------- -----------
test1       1         Root       
test2       2         Center     
test3       3         Company    
==============================
test1       1         Root
```

Comment: A `-trim ' '` instead of the `-replace '^ {1,}'` (which is equal to `-replace '^ +'`) would also remove possible trailing spaces. You could write `'--{2,}'` as `'-{3,}'` (+1)

Comment: Nicely done, though `$CompanyInfo -match 'Test1'` is both obscure and brittle (you're matching against the for-human-eyeballs-only string representation of a custom object). Given that you've already parsed everything into objects, use the OP's filtering approach: `$CompanyInfo | where CompanyName -eq test1`

Comment: @LotPings - do you think i should change my answer? i agree that your tests are rather more robust _and_ somewhat simpler/more obvious. [*blush*]

Comment: @mklement0 - it seems not-too-obscure to me. [*grin*] the OP will likely go with what they already have, but the method i show has been reasonably reliable - and can be slightly faster with larger data sets.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Please see my answer (bottom section).

Comment: @mklement0 - very nice explanation of your point! thank you ... the `.Where()` is a really fast way to get there - one of my faves to use. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell reports an external program's output as an *array of lines* (strings).

To filter such output using string parsing, use the `-match` operator:

```
# Extract the line of interest with -match and a regex
PS> @(MyTool.exe companies) -match '^\s+test1\s'
test1              1           Root
```

Note:

- `@(...)`, while not strictly necessary here, ensures that `MyTool.exe`'s output becomes an *array* even if it happens to output just *one* line, so that `-match` performs *filtering* on that array (with a scalar LHS, `-match` returns a *Boolean*).
- Regex `^\s+test1\s` matches one or more (`+`) whitespace characters (`\s`) at the start of each line (`^`), followed by literal `test1`, followed by a whitespace character - thereby limiting matching to the `CompanyName` column.

If you want to parse the result into individual fields:

```
# Extract the line of interest with -match and a regex, 
# then split that line into whitespace-separated tokens and store
# them in individual variables.
PS> $name, $id, $type = -split (@(MyTool.exe companies) -match '^\s+test1\s')
PS> $name, $id, $type  
test1
1
Root
```

---

[Lee Dailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569882/45375):

- shows you how to instead parse your external program's output into *custom objects* whose *properties you can query*, by first transforming your program's output into CSV text and then parsing that into custom objects via `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

  - While this is very much in the spirit of PowerShell, you inevitably pay a performance penalty, and for extracting simple substrings it may not be worth it.
- then, regrettably, forgoes the advantages of having parsed the input into *objects* by reverting to string matching that negates the benefits of having property-individual matching at one's disposal:

  - applying `-match` - a *string* operator - to a *custom object* LHS results in a hashtable-*like* representation for *display* that is *not* suited to programmatic processing; e.g.: 
    `@{CompanyName=test1; CompanyId=1; CompanyType=Root}`
  - therefore - speaking in the abstract - using `-match` can result in *false positives* - because the matching isn't limited to the property of interest.

In short: If you went to the trouble of parsing the input into *objects* - if necessary at all - use their *properties* for robust filtering, as you attempted in your question:

- `$CompanyInfo | where {$_.CompanyName -eq 'test1'}`
- or, more succinctly, using PSv3+ syntax: 
  `$CompanyInfo | where CompanyName -eq test1`
- or, more efficiently, in PSv4+, using the `.Where()` *array method*:
  `$CompanyInfo.Where({ $_.CompanyName -eq 'test1'})`